# What's the repercussions of using runBlocking{} in an android project

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Let's say I have this piece of code in kotlin,

```
runBlocking {
 withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
  launch {
   // suspending statements here
  }
 }
}
```

I am using this kind of code inside an android project in a BindingAdapter function. However I have read that runBlocking is not recommended in production apart from testing. However, I think that the launch deals with the repercussions of using runBlocking. Is my assumption correct or wrong.

Comment: Why do you need to call suspending functions in a BindingAdapter in the first place? What `runBlocking` is going to do is to block the current thread (in this case the main thread) until your suspending functions complete. Depending on what those functions are doing, this could cause the UI to hang and you could get an Application Not Responding (ANR) message.

Comment: "However, I think that the launch deals with the repercussions of using runBlocking." - what does that even mean?

Comment: If you think `launch()` will run the code in the background, so `runBlocking()` can return immediately then no, this is not correct. `runBlocking()` will block the calling thread until the code inside `launch()` finishes.

Comment: About the repercussions I mean the blocking nature of the `runBlocking()` method. @dominicoder

Comment: OK. Did you try your own sample code, maybe with some print statements, to see for yourself?

Comment: @dominicoder I did and it seems Joffrey's and broot's answers are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you don't need those 3 levels anyway.

- `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` can be merged with `runBlocking` or with the `launch`
- a single `launch` in `withContext` or in `runBlocking` is kinda pointless, and equivalent to just doing your suspending things in `runBlocking`

So in short, your code is equivalent to:

```kotlin
runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // suspending statements here
}
```

And this still suffers from the issues of `runBlocking`. There is no way around it, `runBlocking` blocks the calling thread until everything inside (including nested coroutines!) is done. If you want to avoid this, you have to use a separate coroutine scope to launch your coroutine.